# mysql search string similar to in_array in pjhp

Tags: mysql, string, substring

I have a string @x='2,12,13,1' and now i have to find out whether 2 is exists in the string @x. I have tried using of length function as below.

```
@st=2;
if((LENGTH(@x) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@x, @st, '')))/LENGTH(@st)=1)
    return 1;
else return 0;
```

if it returns 1 then string exists but it is not working as expected. pls let me know is their any other method implement this feature.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: Can you use LOCATE? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use FIND_IN_SET function.

FIND_IN_SET(@st,@x); This function will return the position of the needle string. If it is >0 then string exists else it's not.